# How do I webscrape nested lists in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

Link of website: https://www.zivame.com/rosaline-chromaticity-knit-cotton-top-florida-key.html?trksrc=category&trkid=search&trkorder=relevance

What I want to scrape: Short sleeves style, Relaxed fit for comfort
(Basically the bullet points under Description)

This is the code I'm using currently:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

result = requests.get("https://www.zivame.com/rosaline-chromaticity-knit-cotton-top-florida-key.html?trksrc=category&trkid=search&trkorder=relevance")

soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'lxml')
page = soup.find('div', id="product-page")
description = page.find('div', id="product-basicdetail")
point1 = description.find('div', id="ff-rm text-size pd-b5")
print(point1)
```

Comment: Okay, so you have a URL and you have some code. Do you have a question? In what way does this code fail to do what you want? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is coming as JSON data, you can scrape the data from the source page directly.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

r = requests.get('https://www.zivame.com/rosaline-chromaticity-knit-cotton-top-florida-key.html?trksrc=category&trkid=search&trkorder=relevance')
source_page = html.fromstring(r.text)
json_value = source_page.xpath("//script[contains(.,'window.__product=')]/text()")[0]
json_value = json_value.split("{features:{values:[{list:[")[1].split("]}],count:1}}},modelMetaData:")[0]
print(json_value.split(','))
```